# How to remove Access denied and empty server response error?

Tags: php

I am getting access denied and empty server response error when I open the menu or any Page of my website. This is short time error that gone with refresh or page reload. 
I changed the permissions of my file to 755 but still the error exists

Because of this I am loosing my customers.

Please help me to fix my problem.

My website http://rainingdeal.com

Comment: You need to provide more information: Do you have an Apache Server? Are there any ``.htaccess`` malconfigured? Do you use a framework like wordpress? Can you give us a link where your problem happens?

Comment: Is the folder structure correctly owned and accessible to the apache web server? Which linux distribution are you using?  Depending on the distro, the apache user will likely be either apache (CentOs, Fedora, RedHat) or www-data (Debian, Ubuntu). If they can't access the files and folders you will get permission denied errors